# Scala's method overloading: reason behind a subtle functionality difference with varargs and no-args method defined with or without parenthesis?

Tags: scala, overloading, parentheses

Encountered a weirdness in Scala (2.8.1) in handling an overloaded method where the first is a no-args one and the second takes a variable number of arguments (0..N). Test code:

```
class Test {
  def method1 = println("method1 invoked with zero args")
  def method1(args: Any*) = println("method1 with args " + args)

  def method2() = println("method2 invoked with zero args")
  def method2(args: Any*) = println("method2 with args " + args)
}

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val t = new Test
    t.method1
    t.method1()
    t.method1(1,2,3)
    println
    t.method2
    t.method2()
    t.method2(1,2,3)
  }
}
```

By compiling & running it, the output is:

```
method1 invoked with zero args
method1 with args WrappedArray()
method1 with args WrappedArray(1, 2, 3)

method2 invoked with zero args
method2 invoked with zero args
method2 with args WrappedArray(1, 2, 3)
```

So if running `method1` with parenthesis and zero arguments we get to the varargs method, but in `method2`'s case the no-args method is invoked.

What is the explanation or reasoning behind this weird behavior?

Comment: Doesn't look "weird" to me. Seems like a logical behavior, however I'm not experienced enough with Scala to explain it :-)

Comment: Ok, then the question could be reformulated as "why would someone think the behavior is logical?" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `method1()` cannot be the `def method =` declaration, since it is not possible to call a method without a parameter list passing a parameter list.

```
scala> def method1 = 0
method1: Int

scala> method1()
<console>:9: error: Int does not take parameters
              method1()
                     ^
```

Note that the error comes from Scala trying to call `apply()` on the result of `method1`, which is an `Int`.

Conversely, one cannot call a vararg method with a parameter list.

```
scala> def vararg(x: Int*) = x.size
vararg: (x: Int*)Int

scala> vararg
<console>:9: error: missing arguments for method vararg;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
              vararg
              ^
```

Therefore, in the first case, there's no other possible behavior than what was shown.

In the second example, the first and last cases are non-ambiguous. One can't call a vararg without a parameter list (as shown), and one can't call a method without parameters passing a parameter. One *can* call a method with an empty parameter list without parameters, which was done mostly to make Java APIs more "pretty" -- for example, `.toString`.

The second case -- calling the method with an empty parameter list -- introduces some ambiguity. Scala then tries to determine if one is *more specific* than the other.

Let's take a brief detour here. Why check for more specific methods? Suppose you have this:

```
object T {
  def f(x: AnyRef) = x.hashCode
  def f(x: String) = x.length
}
```

This kind of thing is relatively common on Java APIs. If someone called `f("abc")`, one naturally expects the compiler to call the second method, not the first, *but both are valid*. So, how to disambiguate them? Perhaps, since `String` is a perfect match for what is being passed, one might use that, right? Well, consider, then, this:

```
object T {
  def f(x: AnyRef) = x.hashCode
  def f(x: java.util.Collection[_]) = x.size
}
```

And I call it with `f(new ArrayList[String])` So, what now? Well, `AnyRef` is a class, while `Collection` is an interface, so we might give precedence to interfaces over classes? And what if I had another method expecting `List` -- that's also an interface.

So, to solve this ambiguity, Scala uses the *most specific* concept. That is actually a pretty easy concept to apply.

First, Scala verifies is one is *as specific as* the other. There are four simple rules defined in terms of types and expressions, but the gist of it is that method a is as specific as method b if b can be called with a's parameters.

In this case, `method2()` is as specific as `method2(args: Any*)`, because `method2(args: Any*)` can be called with an empty parameter list. On the other hand, `method2(args: Any*)` is not as specific as `method2()`, because `method2()` cannot be called with arguments of type `Any`.

Next, Scala verifies if one the class that defines one of the methods is a subclass of the class that defines the other. This rule does not apply for this case.

Finally, Scala adds 1 to each method for each of the two criteria above it fits. So `method2()` has weight 1, and `method2(args: Any*)` has weight 0. If the weight of one is greater than the other, that method is considered to be the *most specific*.

As we saw, `method2()` is the most specific one, so it is chosen.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation, I guess this is something I was looking for. The main confusion probably arises from the no-parens vs. empty parens distinction, which is maybe another topic (as you implied).

Answer (score 8):

> Ok, then the question could be reformulated as "why would someone think the behavior is logical?" :)

A method defined without parentheses can't be called with parentheses, so in `method1` case there is only one option.

In `method2` case, call `t.method2()` has two overloaded options to choose from, and `def method2()` is a better fit.

See Section 6.26.3 of [The Scala Language Specification](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CEUQFjAE&url=http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf&ei=urRDTqbePMKCOvWr2aAJ&usg=AFQjCNHwxfm9PxRh99_Ld9rj6oJnBboKQg&sig2=kKqHP6A8jPqjf4HgRXkYPA) for a precise description of how the best overload is chosen: the rules are quite simple and logical.

Answer (score 3):

It is actually very logical. The compiler pattern matches on method signatures and takes the one that matches the best.

I have not tested it, but I'm pretty sure, that you could go a step further and overload the second method like this:

```
def method2(arg: Any) = println("method2 invoked with a single arg " + arg)
```

So if you where to call it with one argument, the compiler would chose this one, instead of the varargs version.

Comment: The one-arg version behavior does indeed seem logical. I would expect the most specific matching overloaded method to be used.

Comment: Right, and the zero-arg overload of `method2` is more specific than the vararg overload.

Comment: Ok. Maybe the problem lies in how the parentheses vs. no parentheses logic feels like to someone fairly new to the language.